# Excluding a div inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Can someone help me with **excluding** a division inside antoher division. My goal is to try to surpasse my children div called **description** to go through a loop in **jquery**. Tried already with jquery function **not**() and **children**()!
Any advice?
This is my code:

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

      var images = $(".images");

      var backgrounds = new Array(
          'url(../img/)'
        , 'url(../img/)'
        , 'url(../img/)'
        , 'url(../img/)'
        , 'url(../img/)'
        , 'url(../img/)'
        , 'url(../img/)' 
      );

      var current = 0;

      function nextBackground() {
        current++;
        current = current % backgrounds.length;
        images.fadeOut(3000, function(){
          images.css('background-image', backgrounds[current]); 
        });
        images.fadeIn(3000); 
      }

      setInterval(nextBackground, 10000);

      images.css('background-image', backgrounds[0]);
      images.css('background-repeat', 'no-repeat');
    });

</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="background">
  <div class="images">
    <div class="container layer">
      <div class="container description" id="description">

        <h4></h4>

        <h5></h5>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see anything in your JS related to exclusion or `.description`

Comment: I also don't see a loop.

Comment: Mistaken I ment the function that goes through my array.

Comment: Tried to present without not() so you could decide where to implement.

Comment: Do you want to crossfade the background image without fading the text?

Comment: Yes. I want that my text doesnt fades while my images fades In and Out in the background. That was the idea.

Comment: your description id should not have the `#` sign. You only use that in javascript/jquery/css selector